# How to make a transparent white gradient background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gradient, android-drawable

I want to accomplish the exact effect on the button background,
 but not successful yet..! any help?

**Here's the image**

[image]

---

**My attempt so far *(gradient_bg.xml)***

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="#e3ffffff" />

</shape>
```

**..and the result not so much..!**

[image]

**The layout**

```
       <TextView
            fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="@string/dummy_big"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

          <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg">

                <Button
                    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_solid_primary"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/view_more"
                    android:textColor="@color/ef_white"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

            </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What's the layout?

Comment: @TheWanderer check now..

Comment: The TextView and FrameLayout need to be inside another FrameLayout. Set the bottom margin on the TextView to 60dp (height + the button's margin bottom).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code may help you to solve your problem

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:endColor="#ffffff"
    android:centerColor="#90ffffff"
    android:startColor="#65ffffff"
    android:angle="-90"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: This is the easiest implementation and it works well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use below text view and align Button below textview using relative layout or some other layout

```
   android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
   android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
```

properties will create fading edge effect to textview.

```
   <TextView
        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="@string/dummy_big"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="verticle"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
```